# Dudas con Servlets y JSP

Tags: java, java-ee, servlets

Estoy desarrollando una pagina web en donde en la página de inicio (en mi caso es mi servlet "Home") deseo presentar información de varias tablas así como también consultas a estas. Lo que he logrado es obtener la información de mi tabla empresas/marcas y mostrar las ultimas empresas añadidas, el detalle es que no se como mandar mas de un atributo por el **request.setAttribute()** ya que deseo mostrar aparte de la información de mi tabla empresas también quiero mostrar informacion e mi tabla usuarios y mostrar mis usuarios destacados así como también de mi tabla noticias mostrar los últimos post (noticias de los proveedores).

Espero su ayuda, ya que estoy super atorado con esto.

Este es mi código de mi servlet.

```
public class InicioController extends HttpServlet {
   @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher rd;
        //mi conexión a mi base de datos
        conexion conn = new conexion();
        //le mando el objeto de mi conexión al constructor de mi claseDAO
        EmpresaDAO fun = new EmpresaDAO(conn);
        List<empresa> lista = new LinkedList<>();
        //realizo la llamada al método que obtiene la información de mi tabla empresas
        lista=fun.MostrarEmpresa("");
        conn.desconectar();
        //Aqui es donde quiero mandar mas de un atributo a mi pagina index
        request.setAttribute("empresas", lista);
        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Al establecer un atributo a la request lo que haces es añadir a la petición un objeto asociado a una clave, la cual es el primer valor del método.

El código:

```
request.setAttribute("empresas", lista);
```

Establece para el atributo "empresas" la lista indicada.

Si quieres enviar otro elemento solo debes asociarlo con otro nombre de atributo diferente.

Ejemplo:

```
request.setAttribute("empresas", listaEmpresas);
request.setAttribute("usuarios", listaUsuarios);
request.setAttribute("usuariosDestacados", listaUsuariosDestacados);
```

Y al recuperar estos elementos se puede realizar por el nombre de la clave:

request.getAttribute("empresas");

Comment: muchísimas gracias amigo, uno pregunta tendrás algún libro o bibliográfica que pudieras compartir para saber mas sobre servlets y jsp.